# 11 functions with duplicate lines of code - is there a way to reduce the redundancy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy, code-duplication, redundancy

I am using Python 2.7.14 with `ArcPy` (no, I cannot use Python 3 as ArcPy does not support that version).

I have 11 defined functions, with different calculations in each. However, besides the calculations, each function has the same lines of code.

Here is a completed function as an example:

```
def NYC():
    MTPZ_fields = ['DBH_Calc', 'MTPZ', 'MTPZ_Buffer']
    buffer_output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
    buffer_distance = "MTPZ_Buffer"

    # Calculation (different in each function)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Tree_Points,Fields) as nyc_cursor:
        for row in nyc_cursor:
            if (row[0]>0 and row[0] <=10):
                row[1] = (1.5*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>=10 and row[0] <=25):
                row[1] = (2.4*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>25 and row[0] <=37.5):
                row[1] = (3*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>37.5 and row[0] <=50):
                row[1] = (3.6*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>50 and row[0] <=70):
                row[1] = (4.5*2)+row[0]/100
            nyc_cursor.updateRow(row)

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, MTPZ_fields) as mptz_cursor:
        for row in mptz_cursor:
            if (row[1] !=None):
                row[2] = row[1]/2
            mptz_cursor.updateRow(row)

    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(points, buffer_output, buffer_distance)
```

The following lines are exactly the same in the 11 functions that I have:

```
    MTPZ_fields = ['DBH_Calc', 'MTPZ', 'MTPZ_Buffer']
    buffer_output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
    buffer_distance = "MTPZ_Buffer"
```

And:

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, MTPZ_fields) as mptz_cursor:
        for row in mptz_cursor:
            if (row[1] !=None):
                row[2] = row[1]/2
            mptz_cursor.updateRow(row)

    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(points, buffer_output, buffer_distance)
```

Is there a way to reduce the redundancy/repeated lines of code in each function?

Comment: Repeated lines of code generally get wrapped into a function.  This is basic programming design.

Comment: Alternatively, you can package the different lines in individual functions, and pass the function references into the common function with the common processing.

Comment: @Rahul has an excellent answer displaying what I was talking about.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
You're asking for individual hand-holding for skills that are included in many other resources.  This is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try decorator. It is not clear what arguments you want to pass and variable scopes but you can try something like this.

```
def nyc_decorator(func):
    def inner():
        MTPZ_fields = ['DBH_Calc', 'MTPZ', 'MTPZ_Buffer']
        buffer_output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
        buffer_distance = "MTPZ_Buffer"
        func()
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, MTPZ_fields) as mptz_cursor:
            for row in mptz_cursor:
                if (row[1] !=None):
                    row[2] = row[1]/2
                mptz_cursor.updateRow(row)
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(points, buffer_output, buffer_distance)


@nyc_decorator
def nyc1():
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Tree_Points,Fields) as nyc_cursor:
        for row in nyc_cursor:
            if (row[0]>0 and row[0] <=10):
                row[1] = (1.5*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>=10 and row[0] <=25):
                row[1] = (2.4*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>25 and row[0] <=37.5):
                row[1] = (3*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>37.5 and row[0] <=50):
                row[1] = (3.6*2)+row[0]/100
            elif (row[0]>50 and row[0] <=70):
                row[1] = (4.5*2)+row[0]/100
            nyc_cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Same way you can define 10 more functions like this.

```
@nyc_decorator
def nyc1():
    pass
```

General example of decorator that I found useful in understanding decorators from programizdoccom:

```
def star(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("*" * 30)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("*" * 30)
    return inner

@star
def printer(msg):
    print(msg)

printer("Hello")

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Hello
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: You may need to learn how python decorator works. For that particular reason, I have given the above general example to make you understand.

Comment: it runs the function being decorated. Just see the example of star and printer function provided.

Comment: you do not put functions in if elif block generally. You just define them. Depending on the condition, you just run them in if elif block.